# Why when I put this piece of code in the file I get HTTP ERROR 500?

Tags: php, localhost

```
<?php

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['address'] . "</td><td>" . $row['company'] . "</td><td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";

            echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>You have no Clients!</div>"
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

every time i put this piece of code into the php file i get an HTTP ERROR 500 while using localhost on MAMP help plz.

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: you even connected to start with? and using the API? Lord only knows where `$result` is coming from also.

Comment: You've a missing `;` after `echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>You have no Clients!</div>"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: ^ which it is............. ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing ";" in the line  `echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>You have no Clients!</div>"`